# if statement float not returning results Unity3d JS/US

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have an if statement that is meant to check a float that increases over time (It's a timer) the current code is this

```
if (Day.DateTime == 1080){
    ClientsTaken = Random.Range(MinNoOfClients, MaxNoOfClients);
    GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent(Brothel).Money += (ClientsTaken *(Cost * GirlMorale));
    ClientsSeen += ClientsTaken;
    Debug.Log("Clients taken = " + ClientsTaken);
}
```

The timer is definatly hitting 1080 but nothing is happening. I also tried 1080f but had the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing floating point variables this way is not recommended due to "floating point imprecision" - the way the floating point variables are internally stored on PC.

Instead, you can use [Mathf.Approximately()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html), like this:

```
if (Mathf.Approximately(Day.DateTime, 1080.0))
{
    ...
{
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. However I now have a new problem, this piece of code needs to be called everytime that Day.DateTime is 1080 (and again at a few other times) i have it set up with 6 different if statements (the only difference being the time) the first 3 seem to work ok, but then the others don't. I figure I need a for loop? but I'm not sure how to set this up with what I'm trying to achieve. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @shane2243 To answer this, we'd need more information. Do you have the code available somewhere? Maybe you could paste the whole class [here](http://pastebin.com/). How exactly does Day.DateTime increase? At what times do you need this to happen?

Comment: this is the function http://pastebin.com/rhHPTVdZ you will notice some bools in there, these are leftover code from when i tried to get it to work using booleans, so feel free to ignore them(and consider them deleted) Day.DateTime is increased in the update of Day using this line E"DateTime += TimeIncRate * Time.deltaTime;" DateTime is a Float as is TimeIncRate. TimeIncRate is also set to 1. I need it to happen at 1080, 1170,1260, 1350, 0 and 90. the timer loops at 1440 back round to 0. I hope i gave you enough to go on EDIT : I also just noticed a typo on line 11, this should be the same as 3

Comment: @shane2243 do you really need to increase the DateTime in each Update? If it's enough to increase the time counter every second (or maybe even every 10 seconds or so), I'd use [InvokeRepeating](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html), like [this](http://pastebin.com/SSsu2Y93) (please excuse any mistakes, I'm C# user). You can then work with integers instead of floating point numbers. As for your IF statements, I need to think about that a bit more.

Comment: Thanks, I only put it in the update function because I was unaware of how else to do it. The InvokeRepeating function seems like a good idea, so i'll definatly try it out. in the line 10 cant you explain what the  0, 1 part does? i assumed that the 1 was how often? as in every 1 second? thanks

Comment: Yes, the first argument is the name of the method to invoke (call), the second argument (the 0) is the initial delay (i.e. after how many seconds should the first call happen) and the third argument (the 1) is the period of calls, i.e. how often should the method be called. So after 0 seconds, the method will be called each (1) second. Also, please, if you find my answer helpful, consider marking it as "Accepted answer", as that's how StackOverflow works - thanks!

Comment: Perfect thank you for your help. I solved the issue by using your invoke function and reinstating my bool systemafter a thorough test it worked 100% of the time. Again thank you for the help

Comment: Glad to hear that! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the check to `Day.DateTime >= 1080`. When dealing with floating point numbers you may not land directly on an integer value.